# How can I obtain an HttpProvider instance from the latest version of Web3.js?

Tags: web3js, provider

How can I instantiate a `HttpProvider` from the latest version of web3?

I've tried:

```
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
```

I am getting this error:

```
var web3 = new web3_1.default(new web3_1.default.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
                                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'providers' of undefined
```